# В чём разница между new Date('2017-01-01') и new Date('2017-1-1')?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime

Почему `new Date('2017-01-01')` и `new Date('2017-1-1')` выдают разное время?

Как парсится `new Date(dateString)` в Chrome?

```js
[
  new Date("2017-01-01"),
  new Date("2017-01-1"),
  new Date("2017-1-1"),
  new Date("2017-1-01")
].forEach(date => console.log(date));
```

---

[What is the difference between new Date(“2017-01-01”) and new Date(“2017-1-1”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43060107)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43060107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"2017-01-01" следует ISO стандарту, и соответствует UTC времени.
Строка любого другого формата, парсится как локальное время в Chrome[<sup>1</sup>](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/dateparser-inl.h?type=cs&l=16).
В общем случае(в других браузерах), это поведение `зависит от реализации`.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Соответствующий исходный код в Chromium](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/dateparser-inl.h?type=cs&l=16)

Парсинг даты в Chromium следует правилам стандарта ES5, кроме следующих исключений:

- Любое нераспознанное слово перед первым числом игнорируется.
- Текст в скобках игнорируется.
- Parenthesized text is ignored.
- Беззнаковое число, за которым идёт `:` - время. Оно добавляется в `TimeComposer`. Число с `::` означает 0 секунд. Число с `.` - также время, за которым должны идти миллисекунды. Любое другое число - компонент даты, добавляется в `DateComposer`.
- Название месяца(любое слово, три первые буквы которого совпадают с названием месяца) распознаются как месяц в `DayComposer`.
- Слово, распознаваемое как временная зона, записывается как `(+|-)(hhmm|hh:)`.
- Старые даты не позволяли лишних знаков `+/-` или несогласованной `)` после прочитанного числа(перед первым числом допустим любой мусор).
- Любые строки, удовлетворяющие и ES5 правилами и правилам выше, будут парситься по правилам ES5. Это значит, что `"1970-01-01"` будет в UTC, а не в локальной таймзоне.

---

### Что это значит?

Для начала, `2017-01-01` парсится в UTC потому что это строка "даты", а не "дата-время". Она также соответствует ES5 определению строки "даты".
Если добавить время - она будет распознано в локальном часовом поясе по ISO стандарту.

Примеры:

- `2017-01-01` - Янв 1, 2017 в UTC
- `2017-01-01T00:00` - Янв 1, 2017 локальное время
- `2017-1-1` - Янв 1, 2017 локальное время
- `2017-(hello)01-01` - Янв 1, 2017 локальное время
- `май 2017-01-01` - Янв 1, 2017 локальное время
- `mayoooo 2017-01-01` - Янв 1, 2017 локальное время
- `"jan2017feb-mar01apr-may01jun"` - Июн 1, 2017 локальное время

---

[Ответ на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43060152/2110496)